# SupportMapFragment (V2) - some clicklisteres like the OnInfoWindowClickListener are not working

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Currenly I am heavily refactoring my app to get it to the current state of the art.
I had everything working before the refactoring, so basically my code should be OK.

My current problem is that e.g. the OnInfoWindowClickListener on the map stopped working and I do not know why that happens:

I am displaying the map in an androix.fragment.app.Fragment. Most of the things work fine - the map is displayed, I can add Markers to the map, draw tracks etc.

Like before I set several listeners on the map in the onMapReady method. Some of them are working as before, some stopped functioning. :-/

E.g. the OnMapLongClickListener works as before. So basically the others also should work.
Right before setting that Listener I also set a OnInfoWindowClickListener. But that Listener is never been called. When I click on a Marker, the Info-Window is opened, but when I click on that Info Window, the listener is not called.
Also the InfoWindowAdapter that formats the contents of the Info Window is not called any more.

I can drag the markers on the map that I have enabled for dragging, but the OnMarkerDragListener also is not called any more.

I don't think that there is a problem with the Kotlin Code regarding this problem. 
I changed the layout to include the mapfragment directly in the layout.xml and changed the  tag to the  as suggested by AndroidStudio. So the map should be inserted in the layout correcly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_map"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llBuddies"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any hints where I can look for solutions to my problem?

Comment: It seems this is an issue within android-maps-utils. Would you mind filing a "new issue" **[here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/)** so it can be addressed?

Comment: @rafon: It seems that you are right. In the meantime I found out that the clustermanager from the maps-utils seems to be the problem. Once I remove it from the maps-object the click-handlers mentioned start working as before.
But I did not have the time to investigate further and try to get the cluster-handler back to work again.
Will file a bug and link to the issue here then ...

Comment: For reference: Filed a bug at https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/758

Comment: Try replacing the androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView back to Fragment. Currently it isnt working properly with FragmentContainerView

Comment: @JoM: Sorry, missed the comment ...
No, that's not necessary. See the github issue above. I was able to solve my problems there.